# How can I properly model a contact between a beam and another part in abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

I have 2 problems in my Abaqus model. I really appreciate your help since I searched a lot, but could not find what I need.

1. I am modeling a rectangle with 4 beam elements, I rendered the beam profile with scale factor 1 and I saw that my model is as seen in the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xAgO.png)

What are those gaps in the corners? How can I get rid of them. The problem is when I sketch the beam, it assumes the lines as the centerline of the beam. Can I change the setting of it in a way that it considers them as the upper bound of my beam?

2. I want to define a contact between the exterior side (upper surface) of this section and another part that surrounds this rectangular part, how can I define the contact pairs so it understands that the contact is defined on the upper side and not the centerline?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that cross-sections are rendered this way but you can define an offset (like that used for shells) if you don't mind some limitations.

It's better to use general contact. It will account for the beam section.